# What's the right way to link pods, like FacebookSDK, to an existing project in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've been running into problems for the last hour trying to find a way to get all of the necessary Facebook modules into my main project. However, every time I try and add them via `pod install` they're added and all the files are there, but only in the Pods subproject in the workspace. However when I try and build I get the no module found 'FacebookLogin'. Every file shows up in the Pods project so it's a build time error.

I'm not sure why the pods aren't automatically linking to the project, as that seems to be the point of using pods in the first place. What do I need to make sure is in my Build Settings and Build Phases to ensure that the two projects are properly connected in the whole workspace.

Comment: The Swift compiler isn't too smart about recognizing pods the first time after installing them. Try running the project immediately despite the errors. It should build and then recognize the frameworks.

Comment: Also make sure you uncomment the `use frameworks!` line in your podfile

Comment: I'm getting all of my Pods rejected as implicit dependencies for i386 and x86_64

Comment: I have the frameworks in my project directly because Facebook gives you the .framework files, but I should still get getting SlackTextViewController working properly as it was before I tried installing FacebookSDK